# Can I use a pair of 2" PVC pipes for a furnace requiring 3" venting?

Tags: furnace, exhaust

Can i use two existing 2" PVC pipes from old furnace and tie them together with a Y connection going to the exhaust of a new furnace that requires 3" exhaust?

New Furnace is 100,000 btu. 2” pipe won’t work due to length of run which is roughly 50’ adjusted. Rather than figuring out how to install new exhaust pipe, I was hoping to use the existing 2” pipes which would otherwise be abandoned. I have another source for the intake side.

Comment: *requires 3" exhaust* - you sure about that? Most are fine in 2" until you reach a certain developed length. Model number? Installer's manual? Number of elbows, their type of sweep, and the length of the whole thing? Don't bother though if the thing on top of the furnace is a 3" flange. If it is, I wonder how many BTUs this freaking thing is.... haven't seen an HE with anything but a 2" flange in 20y.

Comment: It seems the cost of some PVC pipe relative to the cost of the new furnace is negligible,

Answer (score 1):

The square area of 3 inch pipe is 7.1sq inch

The square are of one 2 inch pipe is 3.14 sq inch (total 6.3 for two 2 inch pipes)

[image: area]

The *r* on 2 inch. pipe is 1 inch, and the *r* on 3 inch pipe is 1.5 inch

(1x1x3.14) = 3.14 x 2 = 6.3

(1.5x1.5x3.14) = 7.1

Not enough for air flow.

Comment: Also, two 2” pipes have 133% of the surface area of a 3”, and surface area affects airflow. OP check a flow calculator to confirm the effects of that.

Comment: So, the existing 2" pipe plus a 2" AND a 1" should get him right on the money. Oh, except for the surface area issue, so a total of three 2" pipes should do the job! Or, why not just do it right and pull the 2" and replace with a 3"?